# postgresql schemas in redbeanPHP

Tags: php, postgresql, redbean

I'm migrating from MySQL to PostgreSQL and I would like to use some advanced database layer in PHP. RedbeanPHP looks really nice to me, but I can't find how to use different postgres schemas. I've only found some [old post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/redbeanorm/nPrHb5fGHw8/4Rdb0Zs-ZmYJ) and there is written that there is no support for schemas yet, but it was 2 years ago.

If there is really no support for schemas in redbean yet, wich layer do you recommend? Doctrine, propel or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you have to do and how much you want to rely on Postgresql's features, I could suggest you had a look at [Pomm](http://pomm.coolkeums.org). It works for PHP >= 5.3 and Pg >= 8.4

In any case, whatever you use an ORM or not, you will have to rewrite your queries either to adapt them to the ORM or to Postgresql.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That sounds good, I would like to use as much postgresql's features as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the search path when you need:
R::exec("SET search_path TO schema-name, public");
Or simply:
R::exec("SET search_path TO schema-name");

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).